# How to Create new activity using float action button (fab)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi can somebody have a suggestions on how to make a new activity using Fab  like if you click the fab button it will show up a side transition saying hello world? actually i am creating a chat app and i want to replace the "hello world" with my contacts.

i got a reference link or source code regarding the float action button i mention.what i did is i removed the list view so that only the  fab button is on the screen,  http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/01/01/android-floating-action-button-fab-tutorial

any comments or suggestion will be helpful for me to execute this. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just put the intent to your new activity in

```
fabImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here
                startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Comment: you know how to put transition like if clicked the fab it will show up a side navigation saying hello world? actually i will just edit the hello world and replace it with my contact , because im creating a chat app ,

Comment: then what is the issue, please explain

Comment: it says that the onClick is never used.

Comment: yup. can you click the URL button sir . http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/01/01/android-floating-action-button-fab-tutorial . in that URL i got this project . as you can see in the project is a simple fab , now all i want is when i click the fab it will show up a side transition like in app "hangouts" and will see all contacts sir , and if you will click the name it will show up the contact details of it ,

Answer (score 4):

@warlock
Your answer didn't work entirely for me.
If I pass `this` in Intent I get an error in Studio that it can't resolve the constructor: `Intent(View.OnClickListener, Class<NewActivity>)`.
I had to pass the upper Activity class into Intent or fab's View, like this:

```
fabImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
                // or:
                startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), NewActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), NextActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

This works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should define your activity in androidmainfest.xml as

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
```